# Launch default editor in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I've configured MacVim to be my default editor in Xcode. I can invoke it from Xcode by double clicking the file in the project view. Is there any keyboard shortcut I can configure or invoke to open the file being viewed in the Xcode editor in my default configured editor?

Comment: @Richard: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/FAQ - 4th item down - "How do I configure Xcode to open files in MacVim?"

Answer (score 3):

I am using Xcode 4.3. You can assign a shortcut to open the file in an external editor using the menu item File/Open with External Editor. To assign the shortcut you will need to go to System Preferences/Keyboard/Keyboard Shortcuts, choose Applications Shortcuts, click on the plus button, choose Xcode from the drop down menu, write 'Open with External Editor' in the Menu Title field and choose your shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Option`-`Command`-`O` - if that doesn't work then you may need to go to Key Bindings in Preferences and set it up (I use the BBEdit Compatible key bindings which include this shortcut as standard).

Comment: Option-Command-O opens up in a new Xcode editor window. Not in my external editor.

Comment: @HS: OK - that sounds like a mis-feature to me then - maybe file a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little write up here fwiw:

[image: image of screenshots]

https://tmsh.github.io/visual-guide-opening-files-externally-xcode/